# Deleting %LocalAppData%\Google will delete cached passwords for Chrome, correct?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, security

I have tried to force logout of all devices, but am not sure if it worked or not. I do not have access to the machine, but have asked a former coworker to delete %LocalAppData%\Google from my old work machine. That should delete any and all locally cached passwords that Chrome was using, correct? Thanks.

Comment: Unlikely that will erase the PW, since it is more likely that the PW are stored on the servers at Google.  If you are attempting to secure multiple machines, then the best way is to simply change your PW, assuming that this was your personal account used on that PC you are attempting to fix.  However, if it isn't your PC or your co-workers and you are deleting anything, it is quite likely not his or yours to delete.  As a CEO I can tell you that it might not be as clear as you think, who owns what, even if it is "your account".  I've similarly "been there" with hundreds of employees...

Comment: I work as an IT SysAdmin and (admittedly) made the mistake of mixing personal accounts with my work machine. Not a huge deal, but I want to ensure no one at work can access my personal accounts (Gmail, Facebook, etc), that's all. Of course I realize the passwords are ultimately stored in Google's DC's, I am just talking about client-side (machine-side) local caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in my home lab and YES, this worked for *removing locally cached Google Chrome data*  (bookmarks, passwords, extensions, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that deleting "Google/Chrome/Default/Login Data" will delete specifically all passwords, not touching your Bookmarks (on my Mac: $HOME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Login Data)

After one of the last updates of Chrome it appears Chrome switched over to using "Google Password Manager". However Chrome kept suggesting passwords from the "old" password store without providing any way from Chromes GUI to remove those old entries. Deleting the file above resolved my issue.

Btw. I am not sure, if the location above is also used by the Google Password Manager, but I doubt it.